# Books on science and Torah in Hebrew

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, jewish-books, science, halachic-development

Can anyone recommend books in Hebrew that address the topic of science and Torah?
The types of books that I'm looking for are ones that address the interplay between science and Torah including topics like: interpretation/changes in halacha in light of new evidence, age of the universe, evolution, etc.

Some types of books that I've read so far in English are Natan Slifkin ([Challenge of Creation](http://zootorah.com/books/the-challenge-of-creation)), Natan Aviezer ([Fossils and Faith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881256072), [In the Beginning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881253286)), Moshe Meiselman ([Torah, Chazal and Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600912435)), '[Challenge](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=5fMBnHUiwukC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=challenge%20aojs&source=bl&ots=xdkgtS3RUx&sig=SrDSEVV6mKhhfwx7PGQdG_3InTs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiB6LyTg4XQAhUBwBQKHfYkDJkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=challenge%20aojs&f=false)' by AOJS, Gerald Schroeder ([Science of God](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Science-God-Convergence-Scientific-Biblical/dp/076790303X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477916340&sr=8-1&keywords=science%20of%20god%20schroeder)) and Lee Spetner ([Not by Chance](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Not-Chance-Shattering-Evolution-Published/dp/B00HQMBGN0/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1477916362&sr=8-3&keywords=lee%20spetner%20evolution)).

I don't want to limit myself to English alone, so if anyone has any suggestions for reading material thats only found in Hebrew that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Incidentally, you limit it to untranslated books — how are people supposed to know what's not been translated?

Comment: may want to ask a hebrew site like http://www.hidabroot.org/

Comment: this thread is active so might as well chime in. Recommend this book. https://www.amazon.com/Coming-Revolution-Zamir-Cohen/dp/9659123108/  Zamir Cohen is on hidabroot.org as ray suggests. This book scientifically validates truths of the torah utilizing modern science.

Comment: @code613 I would strongly advise against the Zamir Cohen book... Psuedo science and wishful thinking

Comment: @bondonk I was thinking about that book as well. Is there somewhere a review which "debunks" it? Is it known the book is not strong scientifically?

Comment: @ray I second bondok opinion. The "science" in Hidabroot is trimmed to fit exactly what the writer wants you to know.

Comment: @mbloch http://rebeljew.blogspot.com/2011/08/coming-revolution-by-zamir-cohen.html

Comment: @theash thanks for this

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this blog:
https://madabatorah.wixsite.com/main

It hosts several articles in Hebrew about fundamental physics and Judaism.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya, Daniel, and thanks for this helpful answer. Hope to see you around! You may find [this guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887) useful as an introduction to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this question from a long time ago...

I have found the works of [Rabbi Dr. Michael Avraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Abraham_(rabbi)) to be a very good resource in terms of science, philosophy and Judaism. I contacted him a number of years ago and he only really writes/lectures in hebrew. He has a popular book in Hebrew called "[אלוהים משחק בקוביות](https://www.e-vrit.co.il/Product/1388/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA)" (God Plays with Dice).

He is also a prolific blogger and posts a lot of shutim on his [website](https://mikyab.net/); here is the tag for [Q&A's for Science and Torah](https://mikyab.net/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA/category/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A2) which currently has over 200 responses. You can find further info on this topic scattered throughout his site.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Malbim on the first chapter in the Torah - fascinating how he gives a *scientific* explanation for the sequence of events.

Comment: Thanks. I've read a lot of the Malbim on Bereshit. He tried to use science to explain the Torah, but in my opinion much is not in line with current science. I imagine if he was alive today he would have a different stance e.g. his explanation of how "elephants" (i.e. mammoths) are buried in snow as a result of rapid post flood change in seasons and becoming frozen, as well as 'monkeys' being buried, and explaining how human life expectancy rapidly decreased because of seasonal changes that they didn't have previously, etc. Or that we shouldn't be surprised that snakes speak because "we can tra

Answer (score 0):

Check out Sefer Habris written by Harav Eliyahu of Vilna approx. 200 years ago. (Not the Vilna Gaon) hebrewbooks.com has a few editions, however there is a newer one available in some seforim stores.